# Windows 8 Login Password Out of Sync with Windows Live ID

Tags: windows, windows-8, password-recovery

I'm working with a computer that has setup a local account connected under Windows Live ID.  The user can login to Live ID (like hotmail) from another computer with the correct credentials.  However from the Windows 8 computer using the correct password it indicates.

```
That password is incorrect. Make sure you're using the password for you Mircrosoft Account.  You can always reset it at account.live.com/password/reset.
```

Now, I've used NTPASSWD to reset the password, but it seems that since its not a "Local Account" it wont take the new password or blank one.  **EDIT: NTPASSWD will reset/set a password, but windows will not authenticate using that.**

This account also has a "PIN" the user who also has forgotten it.

I also tried to enable/password set the local Administrator account but it does not show up for login.

Any ideas?

Comment: Has the Live ID password been changed? Is your computer connected to the Internet? To use local password, you have to switch account type to local. It may not work if the account was created as Microsoft account.

Comment: The Live ID password had been changed.  The computer is connected to the internet, via Ethernet, but I cannot confirm since I cant log in to it.   I cannot switch to local account since I cannot login. See http://winsupersite.com/content/content/143456/03lil.jpg

Comment: Yes, it seems to switch to local account you have to login. Was this computer trusted?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reset it through this [link](https://account.live.com/ResetPassword.aspx). I cant think of a reason off the top of my head that the passwords would become out of sync, however using tools like NTPASSWD would never work on the new Windows accounts that are linked to your LiveID.

Comment: Well when we tried to reset it to that link, it said that we had already logged in successfully and why would we try to reset the password.

Answer (score 0):

****The Live ID password had been changed. The computer is connected to the internet, via Ethernet, but I cannot confirm since I cant log in to it. I cannot switch to local account since I cannot login.****

Yes, you can switch to a local account by booting in to a command prompt and enabling the local administrative account built into windows (turned off by default) bootup in to command prompt then enter this command...... net user administrator /active:yes  then reboot and vola!